# Flask keep repeating request on return redirect

Tags: flask

Request keep repeating when return redirect.

I made a button to send delete request to which its going to delete session data with key 'order_list', but    it keep doing redirect until it stopped by the browser

[image: redirect keep repeating]

**cart_order.html**

```html
<script>
  function clearQuery() {
    fetch("/cart", {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("All orders have been deleted");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error deleting orders", error);
      });
  }
</script>
<button onclick="clearQuery()">Clear Query</button>
```

**Flask**

```python
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'THIS_IS_SECRET_KEY'


@app.route('/cart', methods=["GET", "DELETE"])
def cart():

    # for demonstration
    session['order_list'] = {
        'order_1': {
            'marker': True,
            'color': 'blue'
        },
        'order_2': {
            'marker': True,
            'color': 'red'
        },
        'order_3': {
            'marker': True,
            'color': 'blue'
        }
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        if 'order_list' in session:
            print(session['order_list'])
        else:
            print(session)

        return render_template('cart_order.html')

    elif request.method == "DELETE":

        session.pop('order_list')
        session.modified = True

        return redirect(url_for('cart'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'd like the session data with key 'order_list' get deleted, and then redirect back to itself with GET request, and print session which now should be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check from [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302):

> ... For this reason, HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616) added the new status codes 303 and 307 to disambiguate between the two behaviours, with 303 mandating the change of request type to GET, and 307 preserving the request type as originally sent.

So according to this, adding in your redirect `code=303` will do the trick:

```
return redirect(url_for('cart'), code=303)
```

And indeed it works (tested on Firefox). While Codes 302 and 307 enter the endless loop you experienced.

Comment: it works! but why does the endless loop thing doesn't affected POST request? it still use code 302 but it redirect back to itself just fine.
should i also specified response code for POST request to code 303?

Comment: by POST you mean the DELETE i guess. Yes, you should change the `redirect` to include the `code=303`, so that browser will not sent another DELETE to `/carts` and enter that endless loop, but instead will send a GET to `/carts` and finish your "flow".

Comment: no, i mean POST request. I isolated the problem to only DELETE request, my original code with POST that redirect back to itself, work just fine with `code=302`.
should it also be change to `code=303`?

Comment: i suppose you want to make a POST and if successful initiate a redirect to a GET request to same endpoint. so you definitely need to use `code=303` to make that transition (from POST or DELETE or whatever to a GET request)